# Is an async await function, that returns nothing, the same as the non-async version?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm new to using `async` and `await` in my C# code. I just found myself writing a function similar to the following ...

```
class Database
{
  DatabaseConnection connection;

  async void Close()
  {
    await connection.CloseAsync();
  }
}
```

But, is that `Close` method of mine the same as just using the following ...

```
void Close()
{
  connection.Close();
}
```

Or is there a fundamental improvement in the async version that makes it better?

Comment: CloseAsync will perform closing logic in separate task, and you able to await that (if you want). Close will take time from you current thread.

Comment: You should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) about the use of `async void` especially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they are not the same!

Your reasoning might be that since the method does not return anything, you don't have to wait for it to complete.

But the truth is, every non-async method is synchronous, whether or not it returns a value.

For example,

```
connection.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Closed");
```

`Close` is synchronous. "Closed" will only be printed once the closing has finished. However, if you use `CloseAsync` here, "Closed" will be printed immediately after it reaches the `await` statement in `CloseAsync`, and the closing operation will start running asynchronously. This means that when "Close" is printed, the closing operation might not have finished yet.

Also, if you are using a GUI, calling `Close` on the main thread will cause the UI to freeze, since it is synchronous. Whether or not it returns a value, the operation still takes time, right?

See the difference now?